# Interpretation of Logistic equation integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

After solving the problem $$\begin{cases}dP = r(P-T)P\\P(0)=P_0\end{cases}$$

where r, T, and P(initial) are constant, I am asked to use the solution to find the limit of P(t) as t goes to infinity where P(initial) < T. Also, what does this mean for the population?

For the answer for the integral, I got

$$\begin{cases}P=P_0e^{rTt+c} + T\end{cases}$$

but feel like the e exponent is incorrect.

Comment: That is not the solution. Since $P^2$ would yield ~$P_0^2\mathrm{e}^{2(rT+c)}$ which is not balanced - I suggest going back over your calculation.

Comment: plus - I know the form of the solution - this is a very well known equation/solution

Comment: Initially after integration, I get $$\frac{ln|P-T|-ln|P|}{T} = rt + C$$

How do I go about the simplification? 

$${ln|P-T|-ln|P|} = Trt + C$$

is there a simplification of constants here?

$$ln|1-\frac{T}{P}| = Trt + C$$

I am confused with how the constants translate after inverting with e.

@Chinny84

Answer (score 0):

You had the correct solution as per your comments.
$$
\ln\left|1-\frac{T}{P}\right| = rTt + C
$$ 
we can re-arrange by the following
$$
1-\frac{T}{P} = \mathrm{e}^{rTt + C} = A\mathrm{e}^{rTt}
$$
which is simply
$$
P(t) = \frac{T}{1-A\mathrm{e}^{rTt}}
$$
now placing the initial conditions, namely $P(t=0) = P_0$ we can see
$$
P(t=0) = P_0 = \frac{T}{1-A}
$$
or
$$
1-A = \frac{T}{P_0} \implies A = 1- \frac{T}{P_0}
$$
inserting into the solution we have
$$
P(t) = \frac{T}{1 - \left(1- \frac{T}{P_0}\right)\mathrm{e}^{rTt}}
$$
So you are know in a position to figure out what happens when $t\to\infty$ when we vary $P_0$ wrt $T$.